# How to solve this "java.io.IOException: Cannot rename original file" when starting tomcat 5.5?

Tags: java, tomcat5.5

I am trying to run the tomcat 5.5 but while starting the server it gives the following error.

`java.io.IOException: Cannot rename original file to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf\tomcat-users.xml.old`

Below is the full stack trace.

```
`Jun 22, 2012 12:17:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 361 ms
Jun 22, 2012 12:17:44 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.io.IOException: Cannot rename original file to C:\Program Files\Apache Soft
ware Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf\tomcat-users.xml.old
        at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.save(MemoryUserDatabase.
java:582)
        at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance
(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceF
actory.java:140)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInterna
l(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:113)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContext
BindingsEnumeration.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBe
ans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBe
ans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycle
Event(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:693
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Jun 22, 2012 12:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleList
ener createMBeans
SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot rename original file to C:\Program Files\Ap
ache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf\tomcat-users.xml.old
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:805)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInterna
l(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:113)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContext
BindingsEnumeration.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBe
ans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBe
ans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycle
Event(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:693
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Jun 22, 2012 12:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 22, 2012 12:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.25
Jun 22, 2012 12:17:44 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.io.IOException: Cannot rename original file to C:\Program Files\Apache Soft
ware Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf\tomcat-users.xml.old
        at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.save(MemoryUserDatabase.
java:582)
        at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance
(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceF
actory.java:140)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.start(UserDatabaseRealm.j
ava:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1006)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:4
48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Jun 22, 2012 12:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm start
SEVERE: Exception looking up UserDatabase under key UserDatabase
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot rename original file to C:\Program Files\Ap
ache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf\tomcat-users.xml.old
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:805)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.start(UserDatabaseRealm.j
ava:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1006)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:4
48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Jun 22, 2012 12:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start:
LifecycleException:  No UserDatabase component found under key UserDatabase
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.start(UserDatabaseRealm.j
ava:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1006)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:4
48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Jun 22, 2012 12:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 102 ms
```

`

Comment: It's probably a permission issue. Just delete that file and see. Or remove the .old part.

Comment: actually i don't have any file like `tomcat-users.xml.old` there is only `tomcat-users.xml`is available

Comment: Do you have administrator right.. ?

Comment: You may need to give more of that stack trace to figure out

Comment: Please have a look at stack trace

Comment: Are you starting the server through any IDE or running .exe ?

Comment: I tried with both options .1. from eclipse and directly running the bat file

Comment: Plz go through this post. You might get an idea for this problem.            http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Tomcat-within-Eclipse-td2102784.html

Comment: Thanks for the help,it is resolved when i run the bat file as administrator but now the war file i create is not available in the webapps location but when i try to create new war from eclipse it says that that war file id already exist. Also when i type the url with the war name it gives me 404 error

Comment: Restart the server and then try to make war

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12893/discussion-between-tony-and-alpesh-prajapati)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz go through this post. You might get an idea for this problem.

http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Tomcat-within-Eclipse-td2102784.html

Answer (score 1):

Try setting readonly="true" on your UserDatabase Resource element. That will stop Tomcat trying to copy it.

The underlying problem is a permssions one. Whichever user Tomcat is running as, does not have permissions to modify files in the conf directory.